# Certificate Verify Failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=puppetmaster.example.com]

Tags: puppet, configurationmanager, puppet-enterprise

When trying to run the following command from puppet agent node:

```
puppet agent --test --verbose
```

The following error was prompted

> Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get local issuer certificate for CN=puppetmaster.example.com]

I have already added FQDN to my hosts in /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 10):

I deleted the SSL folder in puppet directory and everything worked fine then after.

```
rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/
puppet agent --test --verbose
```

You can check your logs using the command

```
journalctl -u puppet
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @shubham-singh answer, on some system the ssl directory may not be in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/`.

You can run:

```
sudo find / -name puppet.conf
```

to find `puppet.conf` file and look for the value of `ssldir` property in `puppet.conf` and then delete/rename the ssl directory and rerun:

```
puppet agent --test
```

The rerun may give you error and ask to run additional commands at server and agent to clear the certificate.

Follow the commands and then rerun:

```
puppet agent --test
```

and it should work now.

Edit:
If you are still having issue, it may be due to different versions of puppet on server and agent. Check the puppet version using below command on master and agent and make sure the versions are matching.

```
puppet --version
```

Answer (score -1):

I went round in circles on this - i was using the standard Ubuntu repo and just installed puppet on my client machines....
My docker puppetmaster is running 6.14 but the agent I pulled from standard Ubuntu world was version 5.  The bellow as I am sure you will know will add puppetlabs to your repos and then install the upto date version 6 agent.

```
wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet6-release-bionic.deb
sudo dpkg -i puppet6-release-bionic.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install puppet-agent
```

All the answers I have seen to any puppet cerficate type errors just say regenerate your certificate and I could find nothing that offered any further help.

I would suggest check your server and client versions match after my experiance!

Comment: Not my downvote, but I don't see how this addresses the question.  Puppet 6 masters can serve Puppet 5 agents, and the error message reported by the OP is anyway not indicative of incompatible master and agent versions.  If you had a problem similar to the OP's, and the procedure you describe fixed it, then my conclusion would be that performing the package update had among its effects operations substantially equivalent to those described in the OP's self-answer.