# Puppet certificate issue

Tags: certificate, puppet

I have a fresh install of a puppet server and 2 agents, all of them are on ubuntu 22.04.

- puppet server version: 8.2.1
- puppet agents version: 8.4.0

I got this error after certificate signing on the agents:

```
root@ubuntu01:~# puppet agent -t
Info: Refreshing CA certificate
Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get issuer certificate for CN=Puppet CA: 
puppetserver01]
Error: certificate verify failed [unable to get issuer certificate for CN=Puppet CA: 
puppetserver01]
```

I checked those items:

- Puppet Server Status
- The Certificate on the Puppet Server
- The Clock Synchronization
- The DNS Resolution

I tried also the delete certificate and create another again as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387670/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-for-cn-puppetm) but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating a new certificate on the master then doing the same on all his clients. I used this documentation to do it:
[ssl_regenerate_certificates](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).